# how convert lists to lists of json in python?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have two lists:

```
l_a = ['A', 'B', 'C'] 
l_b= [21, 44, 15]'
```

this is exactly the JSON output that I want:

```
j = [{name:'A', value: 21},
 {name:'B', value: 44},
 {name:'C', value: 15},
]
```

how can I convert lists to JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to zip the names and values into a list of dictionaries using a [list comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/list_comprehension.html). You can then use [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) to deserialize this list of dictionaries a JSON formatted string:

```
from json import dumps

l_a = ['A', 'B', 'C'] 
l_b = [21, 44, 15]

result = [{'name': name, 'value': value} for name, value in zip(l_a, l_b)]

print(dumps(result, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "A",
        "value": 21
    },
    {
        "name": "B",
        "value": 44
    },
    {
        "name": "C",
        "value": 15
    }
]
```

Comment: thank your reply!  can i ask  is there any difference between {name: 'A'} and{'name': 'A'} ?

Comment: @pipi `{name: 'A'}` is not valid in python and JSON, the keys need quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
import json
res = [{'name':l_a[i], 'value':l_b[i]} for i in range(len(l_a))]
json_string = json.dumps(res)
print(json_string)
```

Output:-

```
[{'name': 'A', 'value': 21}, {'name': 'B', 'value': 44}, {'name': 'C', 'value': 15}]
```